# Plotly function to convert an RGB colour to RGBA? (Python)

Tags: python, colors, plotly

As far as my limited knowledge of Plotly goes, it represents colours as strings like `"rgb(23, 57, 211)"`, or `"rgba(23, 57, 211, 0.5)"`, but I can't find a function that converts from RGB to RGBA. I want this function because I want to add an alpha channel to an RGB colour in `DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS"` defined in `colors.py`. I know it's very simple string manipulation and I can write my own function, but is there an official Plotly function to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, no such function exists to my knowledge. For anyone looking for a solution, this worked just fine for me

```
def rgb_to_rgba(rgb_value, alpha):
    """
    Adds the alpha channel to an RGB Value and returns it as an RGBA Value
    :param rgb_value: Input RGB Value
    :param alpha: Alpha Value to add  in range [0,1]
    :return: RGBA Value
    """
    return f"rgba{rgb_value[3:-1]}, {alpha})"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone also wants to edit the r, g, b values prior to adding the alpha (I can't believe there is no library function doing this, but I didn't find one either):

```
# imports:
import re
import numpy as np

# constants:
re_pat_color_rgb = re.compile(f"rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)")
re_pat_color_rgba = re.compile(f"rgb\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)")


# helper functions:
def get_rgb_arr(rgb_string):
    re_match = re_pat_color_rgb.fullmatch(rgb_string)
    if re_match:
        return np.array([int(re_match.group(1)), int(re_match.group(2)), int(re_match.group(3))])  # r, g, b
    return np.array([127, 127, 127])  # error


def get_rgba_arr(rgba_string):
    re_match = re_pat_color_rgba.fullmatch(rgba_string)
    if re_match:
        return np.array([int(re_match.group(1)), int(re_match.group(2)),
                         int(re_match.group(3)), int(re_match.group(4))])  # r, g, b, a
    return np.array([127, 127, 127, 127])  # error


def get_rgb_str(rgb_arr):
    return f"rgb(%u,%u,%u)" % (rgb_arr[0], rgb_arr[1], rgb_arr[2])


def get_rgba_str(rgba_arr):
    return f"rgba(%u,%u,%u,%u)" % (rgba_arr[0], rgba_arr[1], rgba_arr[2], rgba_arr[3])


# usage:
color_string = "rgb(110,200,70)"  # also works with "rgb(110, 200, 70)"
color_array = get_rgb_arr(color_string)
color_array = 0.7 * color_array + 0.3 * np.array([255, 255, 255])  # mix with 30% white
color_array = np.append(color_array, 200)  # add alpha
my_rgba = get_rgba_str(color_array)  # convert back to string
```